# How to customize style sheet of Apache wicket HeadersToolbar?

Tags: wicket

I've got problem with rendering table's header .it is not display any color on table. 
I used HeadersToolbar with my data some thing like below.

```
import org.apache.wicket.Component; 
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.AttributeAppender; 
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DataTable;

 import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.HeadersToolbar;
 import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.IColumn;
 import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.ISortableDataProvider;
 import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.NavigationToolbar;

 import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.internal.HtmlHeaderContainer;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item;
 import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.OddEvenItem;
 import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
 import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

 public class CustomTable extends DataTable {   

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5912216230302446976L;

    public CustomTable(String id, List columns,
            ISortableDataProvider dataProvider, int rowsPerPage) {
        this(id, (IColumn[]) columns.toArray(new IColumn[columns.size()]),
                dataProvider, rowsPerPage);
    }

    public CustomTable(String id, IColumn[] columns,
            ISortableDataProvider dataProvider, int rowsPerPage) {
        super(id, columns, dataProvider, rowsPerPage);
        // super(id, columns, dataProvider, rowsPerPage);

        addTopToolbar(new NavigationToolbar(this));
            addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(this, dataProvider));

    }

    protected Item newRowItem(String id, int index, IModel model) {
        return new OddEvenItem(id, index, model);
    }
}
```

I saw HeaderToolbar in details it will generate CSS class "headers" .And then i see in View Source . i have got css class in name "headers".

How to do customize HeaderToolbar to get correctly table row header display color or Can i create new one Css class instead ?

Any one can help me to solve this problem ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your goal.  Do you want the color of the table header to change dynamically, or are you just trying to set the color of the header statically?

If setting the color statically, you can just use css `th.header {background-color: #7FFF00;}` for html: `<th class="header">...</th>`.

If you want it dynamically set I have had success with leaving the class out of the html & injecting it with wicket when condition is met:

```
if(...) {
    header.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "header")`;
}
```

With more information I may be able to provide a more complete answer.  Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and sorry for my question. I jsut want to setting in statically.